# Possible to map subdomains to webapps in a standard Java app server?

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, servlets, jetty

If you have two webapps, foo and bar, in a J2EE app server like Tomcat, the normal way to distinguish them is like this:

```
domain.com/foo
domain.com/bar
```

I'd like to do this instead:

```
foo.domain.com
bar.domain.com
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not something that can be done in a "standard" way - each Java app server has different ways of configuring itself. You will need to look at the documentation for which-ever server you want to deploy to.

For Jetty, that documentation is here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Virtual_Hosts

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 2  entries in server.xml - then each webapp will be the ROOT webapps for each virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

You can define separate JkMount directives in two separate files. Then configure each subdomain as a separate virtual domain, and include the appropriate config file with the JkMount for that subdomain.

Comment: Thanks. Helpful, but we're not using Apache to front-end Tomcat.