# Jetty (Eclipse) listening on multiple IPs

Tags: jetty

1) what's the equivalent configuration in [Jetty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_%28web_server%29) to listen on multiple IPs, as the Listen directive in Apache?

2) How can a sub-domain be configured with different context path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Question 1.**

Assuming you're configuring using a `jetty.xml` file, then you'll have something in there that looks a bit like this:

```
<Call name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
      <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
      <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="8080"/></Set>
      <Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
      <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
      <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
      <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
      <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
      <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

You'll need one connector for each IP you want to listen on.
So, just duplicate that section as many times as you need.
Then for each of them replace the line

```
   <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
```

with

```
   <Set name="host">www.xxx.yyy.zzz</Set>
```

where *www.xxx.yyy.zzz* is the IP you want to listen on.

**Question 2.**

See

- [Possible to map subdomains to webapps in a standard Java app server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822085/possible-to-map-subdomains-to-webapps-in-a-standard-java-app-server/)
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Virtual_Hosts